# Range Attribute for Dates

Tags: c#, data-annotations, date-range, asp.net-mvc-5.2, displayattribute

I have this class overriding the RangeAttribute:

```
public class RangeDateAttribute : RangeAttribute
{
    public RangeDateAttribute()
        : base(typeof(DateTime),
    DateTime.Now.AddYears(-20).ToShortDateString(), DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()) { }
}
```

DataAnnotation for my attribute:

```
[RangeDate(ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
public DateTime anyDate { get; set; }
```

I'm using the method [ToShortDateString()] in that validation, but when displays the error, it comes with the time.. Ex:

```
Value for anyDate must be between 26/05/1995 00:00:00 and 26/05/2015 00:00:00
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a little formatting on the error message attribute:

```
[RangeDate(ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1:dd/MM/yyyy} and {2:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime anyDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot! Btw, I don't need to use the ToShortDateString() in that class, right? Just in the Error message..

Comment: You still need to use ToShortDateString() or ToString() method to convert DateTime to a string because the parameter data type accept string only. Also, you may want to set time value of the maximum parameter to be 23:59:59 instead of 00:00:00 to include the whole day, and you can do that with: DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy 23:59:59"). Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You have to format error message using for example, ArgumentException(String) method and apply formatting spec like String.Format("{0:d}", dt) pertinent to short date. Hope this may help. Best regards,